# standard CSS to set foreground/background color of text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, colors

Is there a standard CSS way of setting 2 colors for a text ? A foreground color and a background one that is right underneath the foreground color but slightly to the right so that you can actually tell that there is a background color behind the foreground one?

Kinf of like the below image but without the 3D effect. I don't care for the background color to go that far deep, as long as you can distinguish that there are two colors. One in the front and one right underneath it but slightly to the right so that the background color is somewhat visible as well.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes use text-shadow to set the underlying text color and color for the background as follows:

```
.twoColor {

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px orange; 

}

<div class="twoColor">David</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set multiple shadows to text like this:

```
text-shadow:    1px 1px #fe4902, 
                2px 2px #fe4902,
                3px 3px #fe4902,
                4px 4px #fe4902,
                5px 5px #fe4902,
                6px 6px #fe4902;
```

This will look very close to your image. A good example is here:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/3DTextTower/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for :)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

[Edit]
Example

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Font colors are set with the "color" property in css but to do what you are doing you can also use the "text-shadow" CSS property.

Have a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To piggy-back off of @Stéphane de Luca's answer, you can chain your text shadows to create as deep of a look as you want:

```
p {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
}
```

See here for different depths: http://jsfiddle.net/3Acmq/